# Android dns resolving block with xiaomi devices

Tags: android, security, firewall

I have problem with my own application only with Xiaomi phone's with lastest official firmware.

When my application go to background state (service and etc), xiaomi firmware?
 blocked any dns query.

Where I can allow dns query for my application? Is security feature or bug?

```
07-12 23:15:31.690 273-663/? D/DnsProxyBlocker: hasUid: restrict uid(10213)
07-12 23:15:31.690 273-663/? E/DnsProxyListener: block dns query from uid = 10213
07-12 23:15:31.691 11572-11619/? I/System.out: [CDS][DNS]Unable to resolve host "microsoft.com": No address associated with hostname
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you decide this problem ?

Comment: Yes, this is battery optimization issues

Comment: How to disable this. My phone restrict google requests and I cant switch  off this. Did you switch block dns req or going to background state ?

Comment: Only user can disable this in preferences, in manual mode. Protect from mailware and other bad stuff